# Why does my batch delete throw an exception when deleting one by one does not

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using `EntityFramework 6.1.3`, I'm trying to delete multiple child items from a parent item. The method below is being used to handle single and batch delete.

```
    private async void RemoveItemsFromGroup(object items)
    {
        var finalItems = new List<RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items>();
        var backupGroup = SelectedLookupGroup;

        if (items is ItemCollection itemsToRemove)
        {
            DialogFactory.ShowConfirm("Clear Group", $"Are you sure you wish to remove all items from '{backupGroup.Name}'", "Clear All", willClear =>
            {
                if (!willClear) return;
                var list = itemsToRemove.OfType<RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items>().ToList();
                finalItems.AddRange(list);
            });
        }

        else if (items is RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items itemToRemove)
        {
            finalItems.Add(itemToRemove);
        }

        _ea.GetEvent<ShowActivityIndicatorEvent>().Publish("Removing Item(s)");

        if (finalItems.Any())
            await _repository.DeleteItemsFromGroupAsync(backupGroup, finalItems).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Reload Groups
        //await LoadGroupsAsync(backupGroup).ConfigureAwait(false);

        _ea.GetEvent<HideActivityIndicatorEvent>().Publish();
    }
```

And in the repository method

```
    public async Task<int> DeleteItemsFromGroupAsync(RTG_Lookup2_Group parent, List<RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items> items)
    {
        using (var context = new MarketingEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                context.Entry(parent).Entity.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Remove(item);
                context.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Attach(item);
                context.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Remove(item);
            }
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

For the sake of testing, on app launch, i am inserting a static group with *19* items.

When I delete all objects, i get an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.'

From here, I thought it was one of my entities throwing the exception, so I started deleting each entity one by one, to my surprise, none of my entities threw an exception.

I wondered what would happen if I deleted *and commit* after each item, so i rewrote my repo method to the following

```
    public async Task<int> DeleteItemsFromGroupAsync(RTG_Lookup2_Group parent, List<RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items> items)
    {
        using (var context = new MarketingEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                context.Entry(parent).Entity.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Remove(item);
                context.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Attach(item);
                context.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Remove(item);
                context.SaveChanges(); //<-- save after each item
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Now when I run this method with a batch delete, the first item is always removed and the second item always throws the exception.

I can provide a db schema if needed but i don't think its a problem with the tables since I can delete one by one.

E: [DB Schema](https://gist.github.com/multinerd/272832f0e07a86bbe20d19b059cfaeeb) and image below

[image]

Comment: It would be good to see the Entity models, so we can eliminate certain possibiities. It's clearly a relationship issue, but there's no indication of relationships in this code besides `context.Entry(parent).Entity.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.Remove(item);`

Comment: Also, have you tried `DeleteRange`, or a cascading delete?

Comment: @cwharris added image and script to create the tables. Same issue with `RemoveRange`. I have a cascading delete on my `1:1`. Still debugging but i speculate the issue lies with one of the 4 `1:many` tables.

Comment: Have you tried using *just* `context.RTG_Lookup2_Group_Items.RemoveRange(items);` without explicitly removing them from the group?

Comment: Got a different error (because my context is short-lived). After a `forloop` to attach each item, i was able to use `RemoveRange`. Can you explain why i was getting the error? I think i have an idea but id like to be sure (also because i cant select your comment as an answer)

Comment: You can use `AttachRange`, too. As for why this works, I don't have a solid understanding. That being said, I assume at some point you were attempting to remove the same record twice within a single transaction, and for some reason EntityFramework didn't like that. But I have no idea. That's just a guess.

Comment: If you remove items from a parent collection EF will merely try to cut the relationship by nullifying the foreign key, hence the exception. So don't remove them from the parent collection. *Only* remove them from the context's `DbSet`.